# Configure Akka actors in Blueprint Aries

Tags: dependency-injection, akka, blueprint-osgi, aries

I'm new to Akka, OSGi and Blueprint. I know how Spring Framework's DI works, so I'm trying to apply that thinking to Akka and OSGi.

I need to be able to inject arbitrary beans into actors and actors into beans. This means actors should be defined in a blueprint xml, right? But Akka's support for Blueprint only allows definition of an ActorSystem (via `<akka:actor-system/>`), not actors themselves. In the end, I imagine, I should be able to tell Blueprint to inject `someActor` into `someBean`, and tell it to either create `someActor` from an ActorSystem, or retrieve it lazily using an ActorSelection.

However, documentation on the Akka's Blueprint support is scarce. Am I, perhaps, doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Did you find any information about akka:actor-system within Blueprint?

Comment: I worked out how to do it. I'll try to post an answer when I get time.

Comment: Phil, you never did post here :) I'm keen to know what you did.